# Text goes out from the image

Tags: html, html-table

```html
<table align="center" width="300px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;background: url(http://www.hubilo.com/theme/6/img/ribbon1.png); background-size: 300px 30px; background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-color:green;">
   <tr>
  <td>
     <p style="color:#000000; text-align: center; font-weight:100 !important; text-transform: uppercase; font-style: normal; letter-spacing: 1px; font-size: 12px; line-height:30px; font-family: \Montserrat\', sans-serif;">SUNDAY 6TH DECEMBER, 2015</p>
  </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

When I see in Gmail , It looks like this.

[image: Image is not showing in proper way]

and if I write two dates,  then it goes beyond the image.

How can i fix it?

Comment: Do you want to add two dates in that ?

Comment: yes... there is a need so. i might have two dates.

Comment: Could you check the below answer and verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put conditions in such case.

like when you have **one** date then give `width` according to your need and when you have **two** dates then give `width` respectively.

this may solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is this you looking for ?

Try to give `width: 100%` then you can easily add two dates.
Or 
You can try to increase the height.

Check here :

```html
<table align="center" width="300px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;background: url(http://www.hubilo.com/theme/6/img/ribbon1.png); background-size: 300px 70px; background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-color:green;">
   <tr>
  <td>
     <p style="color:#000000; text-align: center; font-weight:100 !important; text-transform: uppercase; font-style: normal; letter-spacing: 1px; font-size: 12px; line-height:30px; font-family: \Montserrat\', sans-serif;">SUNDAY 6TH DECEMBER, 2015 <br> SUNDAY 7TH DECEMBER, 2015</p>
  </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i can have width of `maximum 300px`

Comment: Then you may have to increase height.